# `$U$` and `$\mathcal U$` typeset very similarly with TeX Gyre Pagella

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math, calligraphy

I love TeX Gyre Pagella, and use it and the corresponding math font like so:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

However, `$U$` and `$\mathcal U$` are typeset too similarly for my taste:
[image: The letters are, respectively, <code>$U$</code>, <code>$\mathcal U$</code>, <code>$V$</code> and <code>$\mathcal V$</code>]

Since the problem just affects a single calligraphic letter, does anybody have a suggestion for what I might replace `$\mathcal U$` with (from the same font or a different one)?

Edit regarding the [suggested duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386): It does in part answer my question. In particular, it answers how I would go about making the replacement I ask for. I am, however, also asking for a suggested replacement, which I think makes my question slightly different. egreg's comment is a nice such suggestion.

Comment: @Werner How can it be a duplicate?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what your preferred alternative to Pagella's `\mathcal{U}`is supposed to look like?

Comment: I find the math calligraphic of Pagella Math unbearable; `\setmathfont[range=\mathcal]{Asana Math}` will restore a decent calligraphic font.

Comment: @egreg: This suggestion is exactly the kind I was looking for with myquestion. Thanks! If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Mico: Anything that "looks nice" together with TeX Gyre Pagella (I know, this is subjective, but I'm open to any suggestions) *and* has a `$\mathcal{U}$` that is easy/easier to distinguish from `$U$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the available free Unicode math fonts there are just a few possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

Pagella:\par
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

Bonum:\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

Termes:\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

Schola:\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

XITS/STIX:\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{XITS Math}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

Asana:\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{Asana Math}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip

Lucida Bright (not free):\par
\setmathfont[range=\symcal]{Lucida Bright Math OT}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, there's no calligraphic U that can replace the one in Pagella (by the way, they're all horrible, in my opinion). My advice is to change the whole family. Take your pick and transfer the corresponding declaration to the preamble.

Comment: What is the difference between `range=\mathcal` and `range=\symcal`, by the way?

Comment: @gspr With the most recent `unicode-math` you should use the latter.

Comment: Is it only me, or does TGPagella use a different calligraphic font than `mathpazo`? Aha! `mathpazo` doesn't seem to set up a calligraphic font at all!